# having trouble setting up tp link router

Tags: wireless-router

I have followed the instructions that is included in the cd. And the cd said it was successfully configured but I do not get a wireless signal from my laptop. 
I tried troubleshooting network problems(windows 7), and it said this: [image]

I have a dynamic ip address. I tried the google dns server which is 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.
And also the dns server that is assigned by my isp. But none of them work. It still returns the same error.
I even watch this one on youtube and followed it, but didn't also work: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9D8jfyShxI

How am I suppose to deal with this one?Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the router connect to the internet? Can you ping from the router to the primary DNS? If you directly connect your laptop to the modem and bypass the router entirely, can it get online? Can you ping from your laptop to your primary DNS?
You need to troubleshoot this connectivity issue before you get anything wireless involved. Always simplify and remove until you have the basics, then add and find out where exactly it is failing.